# LINQ Select Multiple Elements from a List<object[]>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List which is populated with data from a database.
The object array has say 10 elements when populated
I want to do a LINQ Select Statement that gets returns a `List<object[]>` with just 2 elements. How can I select these elements 1 and 2.

I have tried the following which work for element 0 but How can I get element 0 and element 1 ??

```
var resultDistinct  = result.Select(p => p.GetValue(0)).Distinct();
var resultDistinct2 = result.Select(p => p.ElementAt(0)).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an anonymous object for this..

```
var items = result.Select(p => new { ValueA = p.GetValue(0), ValueB = p.GetValue(1) });
```

Then access each item

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    var valueA = item.ValueA;
    var valueB = item.ValueB;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant ! That did it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Take` extension method:

```
items.Take(x);
```

This will return the first `x` items of a collection.

If you want to skip over some elements, you can use `Skip(x)` before calling `Take`. These two methods are very often used for paging.

Comment: Did I misunderstand the question? I thought they wanted to get element at index 0 and index 1 of the object array in the list, not get item 0 and item 1 in the list?

Answer (score 0):

If you want distinct and then 2 then,

```
result.Select(p => p).Distinct().Take(2);
```

If just 2 then,

```
result.Take(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private class Foo
{
    public int Item1;
    public int Item2;
    public int Item3;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo> 
                           { 
                               new Foo() { Item1 = 1, Item2 = 2, Item3 = 3 },
                               new Foo() { Item1 = 4, Item2 = 5, Item3 = 6 },
                               new Foo() { Item1 = 7, Item2 = 8, Item3 = 9 }
                           };

    // Create a list of lists where each list has three elements corresponding to 
    // the values stored in Item1, Item2, and Item3.  Then use SelectMany
    // to flatten the list of lists.
    var items = foos.Select(f => new List<int>() { f.Item1, f.Item2, f.Item3 }).SelectMany(item => item).Distinct();

    foreach (int item in items)
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

refer to: https://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/09/16/linq-selecting-multiple-properties-from-a-list-of-objects/